# Impossible to bake 8k normal maps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normal-map

I want to bake highpoly tangent normals to low, works fine for 4k textures, takes about 4 times longer for 8k (as reasonable) but gives me some wierd colored texture thats definitly no normal map. Yes, I also changed the texture in the node editor. What am I making wrong?

PS: Do you use TexTools? Why is it so damn slow (exponential, takes forever for a 8k tex) compared to the cycles internal "render button"?

My system: Blender 2.79 (regular build), Windows 7, GTX 980ti, i5
Sorry for the Inglisch ;)[image]

Comment: Cycles is only as fast as how many samples + performance settings you pick for it. But not sure how textools handles it internally. Im going to try and see if 8k does the same for me.

Comment: seems fine here, can you elaborate on your workflow?